# Selection Sort String

Tags: java

I'm trying to have a program where the user enters names and they are put into an array. Then they should be ordered in ascending order by using Selection Sort. I tried doing this but it doesnt compile. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
public class SuperHeros{
   public static void main(String[]args){
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter 5 Super Hero Names");
      String name=in.nextLine();
      String[] Super=new String[5];

      int min=0;

      for(int i=0; i<Super.length; i++){//Enter Names in unordered list
         Super[i]=in.nextLine();
         System.out.println(Super[i]);

         min=i;
         for(int j=i+1;j<Super.length;j++){// Have an ascending list

            int temp=Super[i];
            Super[i]=Super[j];
            Super[i]=temp;
            System.out.println(Super[i]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the compilation error message?

Comment: where is your first `for` loop supposed to end?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign a String into an int value at `int temp = Super[i]`. Also the way you setup your prints and `in.nextLine()` calls were causing issues when running the program.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

  public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] Super=new String[5];

    for(int i=0; i<Super.length; i++){//Enter Names in unordered list

      System.out.println("Enter Super Hero Name: ");
      Super[i]=in.nextLine();
    }

    // Selection sort
    for (int j = 0; j < Super.length - 1; j++){

      int min = j;

      for (int k = j + 1; k < Super.length; k++){

        if (Super[k].compareTo(Super[min]) < 0){
          min = k;
        }

        String temp = Super[j];
        Super[j] = Super[min];
        Super[min] = temp;
      }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Super));
  }
}
```